# Set (ref _..) X NotifyOfPropertyChange(() =>...)

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Is there differences (performance, behavior) between these ways of properties binding?

```
private string _texto;
public string Texto
{
    get => _texto;
    set
    {
        Set(ref _texto, value);
        NomeHome = _texto;
    }
}
```

---

```
public string Texto
{
    get => _texto;
    set
    {
        _texto = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Texto);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is a difference in performance but it could be argued using the `Set` method is using code that has been tested to perform correctly and therefore less prone to bugs. At some point you may well forget to put the `NotifyOfPropertyChange` call into a property.